# [Tensorflow]: cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py - unintended loss reporting

Tags: tensorflow

## cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py

At this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L180), every loss for each tower in the multi GPU is calculated

However, these losses are not averaged, and it seems like the loss from the last GPU is used to return [loss](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L246).

Is this on purpose (if yes, why?) or is it a bug in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L180), note that loss is in different name scopes (tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (cifar10.TOWER_NAME, i))); so if I understand correctly, it is not that only the loss for the last GPU is used; instead, all losses under a corresponding naming scope for each GPU are used.

Each tower (corresponding to each GPU) will have a loss, which is used to calculate the gradient. Losses are not averaged; instead, all gradients for all towers are averaged at line 196.

Note that in this figure from the tutorial, there is no aggregation for all individual loss, it is the gradients that are averaged.

[image]

Comment: But `loss` is a python variable, pointing a loss from a specific namespace (namely the i'th GPU)?

Comment: According to the code, loss is not a python variable, but a Tensor, returned by tower_loss(scope).

Comment: But doesn't that only correspond to one tower - and not the average loss computed over all towers?

Comment: Each tower (corresponding to each GPU) will have a loss, which is used to calculated the gradient. Losses are not averaged; instead, all gradients for all towers are averaged at line 196.

Comment: I added a figure from figure the tutorial. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation, I think my confusion arrived because at [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L258) the loss from the last tower is used to represent the total loss (but in fact it only accounts for a fraction of the loss)

Comment: The loss at that line and line 246 (the sess.run line) doesn't seem to be used in the actual training, and is only used for the later print for debugging information, while train_op in sess.run does use the averaged gradient, which depends on the gradients calculated from all losses.